# How do I handle the reaction of a circle and a semi-circle colliding in java?

Tags: java

I have a circle (not player controlled) and a semi-circle (player controlled) colliding incorrectly. The detection method works fine and returns a boolean for when the collision occurs. However, the reaction does not work properly. The problem that I notice the most is that when the semi-circle is not moving the circle goes straight through the semi-circle without changing speeds. Both the circle and the semi-circle have ints called speedX and speedY. For reference, the class ball is the circle and the class player is the semi-circle.
My code is as follows:

```
if(contact==true)
   runBounce();

public void runBounce()
{
    int speedX=ball.getSpeedX()+(player.getSpeedX()/2);
    int speedY=ball.getSpeedY()+(player.getSpeedY()/2);
    if (player.getSpeedX()==0 && player.getSpeedY()==0) 
    {
        bounceOff();
    }
    else
    {
        ball.setSpeedX(speedX);
        ball.setSpeedY(speedY);
    }
}

public void bounceOff()
{
   ball.setSpeedX(ball.getSpeedX()*-1);
   ball.setSpeedY(ball.getSpeedX()*-1);
}
```

Why does my code not work and what could I do to fix it?

Comment: Could be that speed has gotten larger than the size of the objects? This causing them to "skip over" each other?

Comment: Can you give an example of what speed "x and y" that semi-circle is going and what speed "x and y" the circle are going when you are having problems, and what you expected to happen that is not happening?

Comment: Last line:  ball.setSpeedY(ball.getSpeedX()*-1);....the second one should be Y not X

Answer (score 2):

You last line is your problem...you've used the revers X on Y with a typo.